# how to get/read file name from FileUpload control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to get or read the file name from FileUpload control when borwse button clicked and a file is selected. for example, when browse button clicked, i can browse a file from any location in my computer, for example select video file name al.avi in C://video/al.avi. so how can i get and read the video's name and display it in label control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you PostBack to the server you get the data in the file as well as the file name in the FileUpload control.

```
var fileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
```

This will give you the fileName part 'al.avi'. You can display this in a label.

Here is a [FileUpload example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx) to get you started.