# Why the image does not enter a variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, filenames

aspx:

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="PicUpload" CssClass="btn btn-sm xor"/>
```

aspx.cs:

```
PicUpload.SaveAs(Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\KeepKids\\KeepKids\\pics\\", PicUpload.FileName));
```

why `PicUpload.FileName =""` ?

In one place I do the same action and I get the picture.  and here I get ""

Comment: Where is the filename coming from ?

Comment: do you mean why filename is empty?

Comment: I mean why filename is empty

Comment: coming from folder on computer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get/read file name from FileUpload control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003033/how-to-get-read-file-name-from-fileupload-control)

Comment: I came up with the problem beautiful people! Because I was with the UPDATE PANERL, it was refreshed, and it became "". Now everything is fine Map here How do I unblock sending questions? Block me from asking questions ... I asked a question that didn't exist

Answer (score 0):

I am find from below link:

https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/136183/ASPNet-FileUpload-control-Issue-FileName-is-blank-always-blank/

Can you please try this:

```
**PicUpload.PostedFile.FileName**
```

Something like below:

```
protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 string filename = "";
            if (uploadphoto.PostedFile != null)
            {
                filename = Path.GetFileName(uploadphoto.PostedFile.FileName);
                if (filename != "")
                {
                    uploadphoto.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/" + filename));
                    string path = "images/" + filename;

                }
            }
}
```

Comment: I came up with the problem beautiful people! Because I was with the UPDATE PANERL, it was refreshed, and it became "". Now everything is fine Map here How do I unblock sending questions? Block me from asking questions ... I asked a question that didn't exist

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload File" 
    onclick="UploadButton_Click" />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" Font-Bold="true" runat="server">
</asp:Label>
```

Below is the click event which picks up the filename from FileUploadControl

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(FileUploadControl.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
            FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
            lblMessage.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I came up with the problem beautiful people! Because I was with the UPDATE PANERL, it was refreshed, and it became "". Now everything is fine Map here How do I unblock sending questions? Block me from asking questions ... I asked a question that didn't exist